# handle button click in my lockscreen in android

Tags: android, lockscreen

Hi have implemented my lockscreen succeffully when i screen of or on my lockscreen poopups and i can perform my task to unlock screen now my question is i have a button called emergency contact in my lockscreen which shoul sho the contacts that i stored in my database as a dialog or activity. I tried many windowparams but nothis hapens in my button click here is my lockscreen service

```
public class LockscreenService extends Service {
private LinearLayout linearLayout;
private WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams;
private WindowManager windowManager;
String p;
ImageView img,aimg;
final ArrayList<Bitmap> beforeshuffle = new ArrayList<>(9);
final ArrayList<Bitmap> aftershuffle = new ArrayList<>(9);
ArrayList<Bitmap> smallimages = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(9);
GridView grid;
Bitmap bs;
Bitmap as;
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
BroadcastReceiver screenReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) && linearLayout == null) {
            init();
        }
    }
};
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    registerReceiver(screenReceiver, intentFilter);
    windowManager = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE));
    layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
}
private void init() {
    linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    windowManager.addView(linearLayout, layoutParams);
    ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.lockscreen, linearLayout);
    //   View btnClose = linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.button);
    img = (ImageView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.bs);
    aimg = (ImageView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.as);
    grid = (GridView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    Globalvariable c=new Globalvariable();
    bs=c.giveBitmap();

    String p="/data/user/0/com.example.user.myapplication/app_imageDirrorate/profilerotate.jpg";
    Toast.makeText(getApplication(),p,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d("path",p);
 String bspath="/data/user/0/com.example.user.myapplication/app_Beforeshuffle/beforeshuffle";





    bs=loadImageFromStorage(bspath);

    // Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) i.getParcelableExtra("bitmap");

    //smallimage_Numbers is to tell how many smallimage_s the image should   split

    int smallimage_Numbers = 9;

    //Getting the source image to split

    //  ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.source_image);
    // File imgFile = new  File("profile.jpg"

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(p);
    splitImage(myBitmap, smallimage_Numbers);
    View btnClose = linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.button8);
    btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            img.setImageBitmap(bs);
            as=getBitmapFromView(grid);
            aimg.setImageBitmap(as);
            Bitmap a=getBitmapFromView(img);
            Bitmap b=getBitmapFromView(aimg);
            img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            aimg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            // do something when the corky3 is clicked
            if(b.sameAs(a) ){
            //    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"CORRECT",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                windowManager.removeView(linearLayout);
                linearLayout = null;
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("jhgeiugh","jhgfeug");
               // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"WRONG",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
    View btnemergency = linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.button6);
    btnemergency.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("ghfgh","dgd");
            Intent service = new Intent(LockscreenService.this, PopupService.class);
            startService(service);
        //    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"setted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
        });
}
```

here in btn_emergency i'm trigering an another service popservice which i got from anther SO page

```
public class PopupService extends Service {

private static final String TAG = PopupService.class.getSimpleName();
WindowManager mWindowManager;
View mView;
EmergencyAdapter emeradap;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d("ghfhfd","inpopupservice");
  emeradap=new EmergencyAdapter(this);
    showDialog(intent.getStringExtra("msg"));
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

private void showDialog(String aTitle)
{
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "YourServie");
    mWakeLock.acquire();
    mWakeLock.release();

    mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    mView = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.cononlock, null);
    mView.setTag(TAG);

    int top = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels / 2;

    LinearLayout dialog = (LinearLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.ll);

    TextView close = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.close);
    close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            hideDialog();
        }
    });


  ListView simple = (ListView) mView.findViewById(R.id.emerlist);
    emeradap=new EmergencyAdapter(this);

    String[] emercontact=emeradap.fetchUser("vidhya");
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.layout, R.id.tv, emercontact);
  simple.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    final WindowManager.LayoutParams mLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 0,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON ,
            PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);

    mView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mWindowManager.addView(mView, mLayoutParams);
    mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mView, mLayoutParams);

}

private void hideDialog(){
    if(mView != null && mWindowManager != null){
        mWindowManager.removeView(mView);
        mView = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

but when i click the button it is not going inside the popupservice itself nothing happens but after i click this button the lockscreen is not taking any click listener. All the clicks are disabled i don't know why . Do help me to show an activty or dialog over my lockscreen concept.

permission in my manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Have you added: android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"  ?

Comment: yes i have added all it. i have added the service also. but only the service is there any intent-filter needed